# Google Analytics Real Time Active Users Are Wildly Inflated

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Every RealTime metric is on my website is showing only 4-5 active users (expected) yet my real time count is 90+ (highly unlikely)?

What exactly would cause this? Bots?

[image]

Comment: My "Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders" filter is active.

Comment: I see a similar behavior every 45-60 days for 1-2 hours. Right now Real Time Active users is showing 5300+ users, but the details only add up to 166.  It's some crazy disconnect.  I also know for sure we do not have the number of page requests, or load equivalent to 5300+ active users.